Understanding get-theme-color in angular material m3
I have a navbar with a "a" item and a mat-menu:
<nav class="navbar">
  <a routerLink="...">
     <span>Project</span>
  </a> 
  <a mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu">
    <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
  </a>
  ...

I want both elemets are white. So what I tried is this:
@mixin theme($theme, $variant-colors) {
  $text-color: mat.get-theme-color($theme, on-primary);

  a > span {
    color: $text-color
  }
  
  --mdc-icon-button-icon-color: $text-color;
}

For the span it works fine but for the icon color not (icon is black). If I set --mdc-icon-button-icon-color: #fff directly, it works.
BTW. I'm struggling a bit with angular material m3. If someone knows a good tutorial please let me know. Thank you so much!

Have you tried...
a > span {
  color: $text-color
}
a > mat-icon {
  color: $text-color
}

Good luck with your project.

Try this:
--mdc-icon-button-icon-color: #{mat.get-theme-color($theme, on-primary)};

